# How to remove a node from a doubly linked list?

Tags: c#, algorithm, doubly-linked-list

I need to create a method to remove a given node (the node called "Jack") from a doubly linked list.

here is my code:

linked list class:

```
class DoublyLinkedList
{
    public Node head, current;

    public void AddNode(object n) // add a new node 
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(n); //head is pointed to the 1st node in list 
            current = head;
        }
        else
        {
            while (current.next != null)
            {
                current = current.next;
            }

            current.next = new Node(n, current); //current is pointed to the newly added node 
        }
    }

    public void RemoveNode(object n)
    {

    }

    public String PrintNode() // print nodes 
    {
        String Output = "";

        Node printNode = head;
        if (printNode != null)
        {
            while (printNode != null)
            {
                Output += printNode.data.ToString() + "\r\n";
                printNode = printNode.next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Output += "No items in Doubly Linked List";
        }
        return Output;
    }

}
```

Execute button code:
I have already added 3 nodes as you can see and I want to remove the "Jack" node.

```
private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoublyLinkedList dll = new DoublyLinkedList();
        //add new nodes 
        dll.AddNode("Tom");
        dll.AddNode("Jack");
        dll.AddNode("Mary");
        //print nodes 
        txtOutput.Text = dll.PrintNode(); 

    }
```

Comment: @deviantfan the problem is I don't know how to create a method that removes the node.

Comment: @nintendojunkie I haven't tried anything because I have no idea how to do it, I am very new to this.

Comment: To whoever is voting to close this question as "it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem." - Clearly, there is enough information to diagnose the problem. I don't see why this should be closed.

Comment: I agree with dcastro, the problem was diagnosed quite easily and quickly. I would gladly provide more information but I honestly don't know what else I could add to it. If anyone has any suggestions I would be happy to update the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the node `n`

   1. if `n.Next` is not `null`, set `n.Next.Prev` to `n.Prev`
   2. if `n.Prev` is not `null`, set `n.Prev.Next` to `n.Next`
   3. if `n == head`, set `head` to `n.Next`

Basically, you find the node you want to remove, and make the node to its left point to the node to its right, and vice-versa.

To find node `n`, you can do something like this:

```
public bool Remove(object value)
{
    Node current = head;

    while(current != null && current.Data != value)
        current = current.Next;

    //value was not found, return false
    if(current == null)
        return false;

    //...
}
```

Note: these algorithms usually involve two invariants. You have to make sure that, at all times, the first node's `Prev` property and the last node's `Next` property are null - you can read this as: "no node comes before the first node, and no node comes after the last node".

Comment: this makes sense to me, but how to I find the node?

Comment: @SpiritualEvolution As a side note, you'll want to make your `head` and `current` fields private and, perhaps, consider making your list generic as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is so simple, I understand it very well now. As for the generic list, that is my next step. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your code should include `Previous` pointer to make it doubly linked list.

```
public void RemoveNode(object n) {
     Node lcurrent = head;

     //assuming data is an object
     while(lcurrent != null && lcurrent.Data != n) {
         lcurrent = lcurrent.Next;
     }
     if(lcurrent != null) { 
        //update current
        if(lcurrent == current) current = current.Previous;

        if(lcurrent == head) {
           head = lcurrent.Next;
        } else {
           lcurrent.Previous.Next = lcurrent.Next;
           lcurrent.Next.Previous = lcurrent.Previous;
           lcurrent.Next = null;
           lcurrent.Previous = null;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a few problems with your algorithm. `head.Previous!=null` will always be false, since no node comes before the head. Also, I'm pretty sure `n` will be the value of the node, not the node itself, so the cast will fail.

Comment: @dcastro you are right.. my bad.. I somehow got fixated with circular linked list in my mind